# make a javascript runtime environment for jekyll blog using gitlab-ci without gems?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby, coffeescript, gitlab-ci

I am making a jekyll blog in gitlab and I have managed to create the html and link and add the scss files too but now when I added the coffeescript I checked that there is a gem which i need for jekyll to generate the javascript files from coffeescript and that hem is jekyll-coffeescript.

then I made the .gitlab-ci.yml file where i did the usual things

```
image: ruby:2.4.2

cache:
 paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
  - bundle install --path vendor/

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
   - master
```

now it gives an error where is basically says

Could not find a JavaScript runtime

so I added the gem 'therubyracer'

Is there a way to use nodejs as the javascript runtime environment? and how do I do that? and how do I use the 'execjs' gem

I do not want to use the gems basically, I want to use something like nodejs etc.

but i would like to know how to use the execjs gem too, I saw the readme file that was in its github repository but did not understand the coffeescript example.